# Mercurial show number of commits ahead of "origin"

Tags: bash, mercurial

I'm thinking in git terms here ... is it possible to see how many local commits you have made ahead of the origin? As in git, if you type `git status` it will tell you

```
Your branch is ahead of blah by blah blah
```

Is there a similar thing in Mercurial? I know there is hg outgoing but I don't want a command that hits the server as I want to put the output in my prompt (like the commonly implemented bashrc funciton `num_git_commits_ahead`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `hg summary --remote` will give you what you want, but it will give you a bit extra, too.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that hg summary did what it did. Should have rtfmd. I achieved the count by doing this:

Comment: Couldn't edit above: Thanks, I didn't realize that hg summary did what it did. Should have rtfmd. I achieved the count by doing this: num=$(hg summary | grep "update:" | wc -l | sed -e 's/^ *//') . The sed is to remove the leading spaces coming out of wc.

Comment: Actually, hg summary --remote is really closer to what I want, and as there is no way to find what I'm looking for without contacting the server, this isn't really possible to put in the bash prompt with the current version of mercurial.