# Mercurial view number of commits ahead of upstream

Tags: mercurial

This is an extension of the following question:
[Mercurial show number of commits ahead of "origin"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6503489/4126652)

I want to find out the number of commits yet to be pushed to the remote repository without contacting the remote (So that I can add it to my prompt).

In git I can do that with:

```
git rev-list branchname@{upstream}..HEAD | wc -l //I am counting the number of lines to get the number of commits by which i am ahead.
```

The original answer advices to use:

```
hg summary --remote
```

But this contacts the remote repository and takes quite sometime, so putting it in  prompt seems a bad idea.

Does anyone know if mercurial allows to do this, since the original question is quite outdated, i thought some new method or extension might have come up.

Comment: With Git, instead of `| wc -l` you should use `--count`: `git rev-list --count '@{u}..'` to count commits ahead of the current branch's upstream, if there is an upstream for the current branch.

Answer (score 2):

`hg outgoing` : log of everything that has yet to be pushed (but it does contact the remote repository)

`hg log -r "draft()"` : log all of the commits that are in draft phase in your repository (without contacting remote).  This doesn't definitively mean that they are not in the remote repo, but it's very close.

You can use `--template` [templates](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/templates) to customize the output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes the draft one is pretty close, i though of it too, but then it entirely depends on the client whether it is a publishable repo or not, I could probably change it in the hgrc file.