# Extension or way to cache remote heads in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I would need, much like Git does, for Mercurial repos to have a cache of remote head ids. The purpose is to have an instant `hg outgoing` (or equivalent, I don't even mind writing code). This id cache would be updated every `pull` or `push`, so that I know at all times which changeset need to be pushed and do a report on a few dozen repositories without waiting forever for network roundtrips to remote. An extension or some already-made hook+script would be nice.

Comment: What is your question? If you want to develop such feature I'd try contacting Mercurial devs via mailing list or something.

Comment: Well, I'd be surprised if a solution to this didn't exist because Mercurial was used on a large scale long before git came around and it's such a basic dev process feature, I just didn't find it. I'm still hoping someone will paste a link and say "there it is, dummy".

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of "do a report on a few dozen repositories" ?  Are you pushing to multiple different locations?

Comment: @StayOnTarget, not necessarily. I just have a lot of repositories, and they can have one or more local clones; basically I have any number of local projects, each project can clone any number of libraries if a change is needed to a library in the context of that project. Then the changes from all local clones need to be centralized and organized into releases.

Comment: @StayOnTarget so it's just about running `hg outgoing` on a lot of local repos, even if to a single (default) remote per repo, the rountrips to the remote server take too much.

Comment: So the question mainly is about how to speed up outgoing or make it instantaneous...  given that other people could have pushed and/or added new heads, I'm not sure it is possible for outgoing to function reliably without comparing to the remote?

Comment: @StayOnTarget - I don't see why not, the local repo can store which revision it has last pulled (or pushed) for every head. So it's just a question of showing, per remote per branch, commits that are downstream of the last known synced commit. What others do on the remote repo shouldn't be relevant as long as commits are immutable (no `strip` or `mq` funny business).

Comment: I just meant that the push may fail anyway if there are new heads that aren't in the local repo.

Comment: That doesn't affect me too much, the pushes can be manually done as long as we know about them. In fact doing a trunk merge locally is usually the way to go, as opposed to a great number of lingering branches on the central server that need to be merged all at once without their relevant context. 

So it's nothing more than what git does, which is keep a pointer to the last know heads state in the remote repo(s), so I can just quickly see what's "dirty" in the local projects and their cloned libraries.

Comment: @StayOnTarget hg already has "phases", but that's too broad, as any push will promote the commits to "public" even if they were not pushed to the upstream repo.

Comment: I was thinking phases would be close to what you want, but it does rely on them being used correctly. Its an optional feature plus there are ways for people to use it improperly.

Comment: Looking through my army of clones, I see some of them have a `.hg/cache/branch2-base`, which, where it exists, it seems to contain some sort of remote head id list. But I can't find any documentation for it and it doesn't seem to exist on all clones,

Comment: Seems 5 years, 6 months ago the same question had the same "answer": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737424/mercurial-view-number-of-commits-ahead-of-upstream ; so I'm considering if the best mercurial "plugin" that does what git does is not... `git` :) It will be a painful and error-prone switch but I'm just tired of lack of productivity features.